# Issue Insert/Update EF Core DbContext in Azure QueueTrigger Function (Multi-threading)

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, entity-framework-core-2.1

I´m getting PK Violation Exception when using **EF Core 2.1** *DbContext* in an **Azure QueueTrigger function**. Guess is due to the nature of DbContext not being *thread-safe*, and the Azure Function running different instances in parallel. I have read quite a few, but I can´t find a good approach to solve this.

Here is my scenario (producer-consumer pattern):

I have a **Scheduled Azure Function** that is calling an API to get Projects from different external systems. To get all the required info for a project, I need to run different Queries to other external services, so I´m decoupling this to another Azure function, so the Scheduled function just queues a message per Project, as “*Sync Project ID 101*”.

Another **QueueTrigger Function** fires every time a message is queued, so, it means **different instances running in parallel**. This function must gather all the data of a specific *Project*, and that means more calls to other external services / APIs, to (some kind of) aggregate all the info about a *Project*. IMHO it´s good to do it that way, as I can process multiple Projects in parallel, and I can scale the Function if I need it.

Once I have all this *Project* info, I want to persist it in a SQL DB using EF Core (and here comes the issue)

Project data includes Users in the Project, and each user have a specific *GUID* as PK (coming from the external system). That means I can have repeated Users IDs in different Function instances, and here is the problem, as when I try to persist User info in a SQL Table, I can get PK Duplication exception, as multiple Function instances can try to Insert the same User at the same time (when the instance A check if user exists, it gets False, but another instance B is actually adding this User, so when instance A tries the Insert, it fails).

Guess I can lock DbContext somehow, but not sure if is good, as I also have a website doing Queries to the SQL DB (read-only queries for now, but could be updates in future too).

Another idea could be to send the entire Project info to another Queue / Blob file, and have another function in **Singleton** mode that Insert the data into SQL.

I´ve created this project simplifying my scenario, but enough to reproduce the issue and understand the problem.
https://github.com/luismanez/queuetrigger-efcore-multithreading

Any other ideas or recommended approaches? (open to change the architecture if find something better)

Many thanks!

Comment: Durable Functions Pattern #2: Fan-out/fan-in seems a very good option:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "more easy" way could be to do some kind of upsert in the database. There is a sample of how to do that with EF Core: https://www.flexlabs.org/2018/02/adding-upsert-support-for-entity-framework-core

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, looks like a good approach. Finally I changed my architecture using the Durable function fan-out/in pattern because it makes more sense in my scenario, and also fixes this issue cos the persist data process is running in-serial. However, marking your answer, as seems a valid approach more specific to the original question. Haven´t tested it though. Many thanks!

Comment: Ok. Keep care with Durable functions because they make potential concurrency issues less predictable than classic workflows. And in a fan-out scenario issues are harder to track. (my own experience with durable functions)